# Angular2- How do I install a typing file?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to include some of these typings: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Now I have the following file:

```
{
    "ambientDependencies": {
      "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
      "systemjs": "registry:dt/systemjs#0.18.4+20160417155658",
      "jquery": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jquery/jquery.d.ts#4cdfbe96b666eec5e1defbb519a62abf04e96764",
      "googlemaps.infobubble": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/googlemaps.infobubble/google.maps.infobubble.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
    }
  }
```

How do I install these and how can I check if they are installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a typings file already all you need to run is:

```
$ typings install
```

You need typings installed to run that command:

```
$ npm install -g typings
```

If you need more typings:

```
$ npm install dt~jquery --save --global
```

The flag `dt~` refers to the source: DefinitelyTyped.

You can learn more [here](https://github.com/typings/typings)

## Update: Solving "no dependencies" in release >= typings@1.0.0

There has been a change in typings you are probably using an old version of the config...

You need to do the following:

Remove previous config:

```
$ rm -r typings.json typings
```

Update Typings:

```
$ npm install -g typings
```

Install new config:

```
$ typings init
$ typings install --save --global dt~es6-shim
$ typings install --save --global dt~systemjs
$ typings install --save --global dt~jquery
$ typings install --save --global dt~google.maps.infobubble
```

The result should be like the following:

```
{
  "version": false,
  "dependencies": {},
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "google.maps.infobubble": "registry:dt/google.maps.infobubble#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160417213236",
    "systemjs": "registry:dt/systemjs#0.18.4+20160417155658"
  }
}
```

Save this file and the next time you need to reinstall:

```
$ typings install
```

Will do the job!

Comment: after this command: $ typings install it says no dependencies and the infobubble folder is not added

Comment: After some hours trying all the different tips, this is the first reply that helped me getting jquery typings installed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the `typings` folder at the root of your project. If they are present in it (see sub folders), they are installed...

**Updated**

As stated by @inukkusu, if you want to install what you define within the `typings.json` file use the command: `typings install`.

Comment: And how do I run the typings.json file to install these?

Comment: If I do this it says no dependencies but i definitely defined them in typings.json

Comment: Neither is the folder infobbuble

Comment: Can you please help me?